# How can I get the selected nodes in the jstree?

Tags: php, jquery, jstree

i am using dynamic value for initially_select & open which is checked_id. in checked_id, i have assigned `'"skillTree_1576","skillTree_1573"'` value but its not working... if the same value i pass statically then its working fine.... following is source code

```
$("#"+node_id+"Edit").live("click", function(){
            $('#'+node_id+'Lookup').show(); 
            $('#'+node_id+'Values').hide(); 
            $("#"+node_id).bind("check_node.jstree", function (e, data) {//check all parent nodes
                var currentNode = data.rslt.obj.attr("id");
                var parentNode =  data.rslt.obj.attr("parent_id");
        $("#"+node_id).jstree("check_node", "#"+parentNode);
            }).bind("uncheck_node.jstree", function (e, data) {//uncheck all child nodes
                var currentNode = data.rslt.obj.attr("id");
                var allChildNodes = data.inst._get_children(data.rslt.obj);
        allChildNodes.each(function(idx, listItem) { 
        var nid = $(listItem).attr("id");
        $("#"+node_id).jstree("uncheck_node", "#" + nid);
            });
        }).jstree({"0":"","plugins":["themes","json_data","ui","search","hotkeys","checkbox"],"checkbox":{
                "real_checkboxes":true,"two_state":true,"checked_parent_open":true,"override_ui":true
            },"themes":{"theme":"classic","dots":true,"icons":false},"json_data":{
                "ajax":{"url":baseUrl+url,"data":function (n) { 
                        return {'node_name': node_id, 'operation' : 'lookup_children', 'id' : n.attr ? n.attr('id').replace(/[a-z0-9A-Z]+_/g,'') : 0 }; 
                        $('#'+node_id+'emptySearch').hide(); },"success":function(){}}},"search":{
                        "show_only_matches":false,"ajax":{
                            "url":baseUrl+url,"data":function (str) {if(str.length > 2 ) { 
                                    return {'node_name': node_id, 'operation' : 'search', 'search_str' : str}; } },"success":function (data) {
                                if(data.length == 0) { $('#'+node_id+'emptySearch').show(); 
                                } else {    
                                    $('#'+node_id+'emptySearch').hide();}}}},"ui":{"initially_select":[checked_id] },"core":{
                                    "initially_open":[checked_id],"load_open":true,"open_parents":true}});
                           // alert ('hello : '+checked_id);
                        });
```

if any one have idea about it please help me.. thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

For selecting multiple id you can use as below:

```
 $("input[id^='skillTree_']")....
```

`^` is used for starting with define string.

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: in jstree there is option for multiple selection which is called initially_select.. if i pass static value in this field its working fine but if i pass variable cheked_id its not working... so that i want how can i figure-out this problem?

Comment: @ratneshdwivedi If you set fiddle then I will help.